# Как составить Regex для исключения предыдущих символов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

составляю regex для переработки данных в элементе данных Zabbix`а.
Но так как я не силен в регулярках отсюда возник в следующий вопрос
В элементе приходит следующая информация:

> 123456;789012;порядок цифр;снова порядок;и так одиннадцать раз

Порядок цифр идет различный но каждый порядок идет через точку с запятой.
Первый порядок 123456 получаю соответственно следующим regex`ом

> [0-9]+

Так как для каждого требуемого элемента данных нужен порядок символов до каждой точки с запятой
Второй порядок пытаюсь получить следующим образом:

> [^0-9][0-9]+

Удалив первый порядок, я получаю следующий, но перед ним у меня возникает точка с запятой от предыдущего порядка, которую я всеми способами не разобрался как удалить регуляркой.
Подскажите люди добрые, как мне получить каждый порядок цифр, не получая предыдущего, и не имея символов в нем.

Comment: Какая изначально задача стоит? Получить по очереди все группы цифр?
Выражение (\d)+ должно помочь, оно вернёт все 11 совпадений. С zabbix`ом не знаком, может там нельзя так использовать регулярки

Comment: Задача состоит получить каждым новым элементом данных в заббиксе каждую последующую группу.
Если быть точнее, то на кадждую группу цифр, должен быть свой элемент.

Comment: 1 - Элемент должен получить из общей группы первые цифры до точки с запятой
2 - Второй элемент вторую группу цифр с общего элемента данных

Comment: т.е. нужно именно 11 регулярных выражений для разбора одной строик?

Comment: Именно так и нужно

Comment: попробуй \d+(?=(;\d+){10};$) - для 1го  \d+(?=(;\d+){9};$) - для 2го ...
\d+(?=(;\d+){1};$) - для 10го   и \d+(?=;$) для 11го

Comment: Данная регулярка не работает, как не работает и в regex101

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=109599

Comment: да, не учел что символ ; может отсутствовать в конце. И что бы выражение сработало, нужно полностью написать строку со всеми 11ю группами цифр. Так попробуй 
\d+(?=(;\d+){10};?$)  https://regex101.com/r/MWiKup/1

Comment: Спасибо, мне помог следующий способ
 (?<=^\d{6};\d{6};)\d{6}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог следующий способ:

```
^\d+(?=;) # 1 элемент
(?<=^\d{6};)\d{6} # 2 элемент
(?<=^\d{6};\d{6};)\d{6} # 3 элемент
```

Comment: Эх, надо было не только на тостере ответ оформлять))